# Number of linearly independent solutions after Fourier transform of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-transform

For linear ODEs the number of linearly independent solutions is equal to the order of the equation. However, it's not clear to me how to recover the same number of solutions in I'm using Fourier transform to solve the equation.

For example, the Airy equation (with unspecified boundary conditions):

$$y''(x)-x y(x)=0$$

Using Fourier transform, we get:

$$-k^2 \hat{y}(k)-i \hat{y}'(k)=0$$

Which is a separable first order ODE.

So we get:

$$\hat{y}(k)=A e^{i k^3/3}$$

Where we only have one integration constant. Inverse transform doesn't lead to any additional constants.

> So, what should I do to recover two linearly independent solutions of the original equation?
>
> Should the boundary conditions always be specified before applying Fourier transform?

Comment: Isn't your $A$ complex? What about the real and imaginary parts of $e^{ik^3/3}$?. There you have two real independent solutions.

Comment: Are we working over reals or complexes?

Comment: @GReyes, it's complex, yes. Are you sure it gives two independent solutions?

Comment: @mathreadler, the variable is real

Comment: Same as needing a linear combination with sin and cos solving real case but just one complex exponential in complex case (if you remove "times x").

Comment: @mathreadler, but one exponential is not enough, is it? We have $A e^{ix}+B e^{-ix}$

Comment: Fourier transform of real function is always Hermitean. The equation system will be degenerate. I.e. A and B won't have full degrees of freedom in complex plane.